# How to know whether is a dir from the input line java

Tags: java, cmd, dir

I am doing a homework and I have a trouble that I don't know how to justify weather is it a directory of my input from the Console.
  for example
  when I input dir c://dir/dcd (like the cmd of Windows) What I want to do is to find the file and dir from c://dir/dcd ,but how could I know that c://dir/dcd is a dir
 If you know how to do it or you have some idea about it, please tell me.
 thanks.

Comment: `java.io.File#isDirectory`?

Comment: In order to learn new API's, review File Api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Do you think you are the first person to have this question? Did you at least made a search in google?

Comment: no no no ,I think that both of you misunderstand me , I know that the File class could do this , But What I asked is that I input a String randomly ,shall I need to test all of  the string I input ,like c:/dd/  c d,as you know the first one is dir but the last two one is not, so I want to know the exact dir in a more efficient way .Is there anyway that do no deed to test all the char of the string ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the File API can be of help here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: As @MadProgrammer says, File.isDirectory() is probably what you need.

Comment: No No No, I think that you are all misunderstand me

Answer (score 0):

Try checking it with this: `new File(<yourArgStringHere>).isDirectory()`.